Mostar únicamente los datos pertenecientes a un User_ID
tengo un código que he comprado, es para vender cuentas streaming, la situación es quela persona que me lo vendió no me responde, tengo conocimientos MUY BÁSICOS de programación pero al ver el código de verdad no se como solucionar el error que tiene.
Tengo una tabla accounts
ID | email | passwordemail | password | dateto | status | user_id | service_id
Tengo 2 roles de usuarios: super_admin y resseller
la dinámica es la siguiente:
Como administrador puedo registrar una nueva cuenta ligada a un servicio especifico (por ejemplo una cuenta de Netflix de 3 perfiles).
[
Al momento de crear esta cuenta el administrador decide si puede ofertar o poner esta cuenta disponible o visible en al tienda.
El revendedor inicia sesión y puede ir a la tienda a ver la disponibilidad, la puede comprar y ya va a estar visible entre su lista de cuentas...

el problema ocurre cuando se vana  realizar las suscripciones a las cuentas.
Que el revendedor puede ver TODAS las cuentas y necesito que se listen SOLO sus cuentas compradas, que si observan en la primera imagen tendrian que ser las asignadas al user_id correspondiente en la tabla cuentas.
El revendedor tiene listado sus cuentas correspondientes:

Pero al realizar una nueva suscripción puede ver TODAS LAS CUENTAS del sistema

y lo que necesito es que solo liste las cuentas que posee en este caso, no todas las del sistema.
==========================================================
mis vista Add-edit.blade (para realizar la suscripción) es la siguiente:
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', $title)

@section('content')
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-success">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2><i class="fas fa-star"></i> {{ $title }}</h2>
                </div>
                @include('admin.partials.form', ['element'=>'subscriptions', 'type'=>$type, 'id'=>@$data->id])
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Servicio:</label>
                            <select name="service_id" class="form-control @error('service_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach($services as $service)
                                    <option value="{{$service->id}}">{{$service->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('service_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Cuenta:</label>
                            <select name="account_id" class="form-control @error('account_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('account_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Perfil:</label>
                            <select name="profile_id" class="form-control @error('profile_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('profile_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Cliente:</label>
                            <select name="customer_id" class="form-control @error('customer_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option>Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach($customers as $customer)
                                    <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->name}} ({{$customer->phone}})</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('customer_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Monto:</label>
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="amount" class="form-control @error('amount') is-invalid @enderror" />
                            @error('amount')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Vencimiento:</label>
                            <input type="date" name="date_to" class="form-control @error('date_to') is-invalid @enderror" />
                            @error('date_to')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        @include('admin.partials.buttons',['cancelRoute'=>'subscriptions.index'])
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop

@section('js')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select").select2();
            $("select[name='service_id']").change(function(){
                let id = $(this).val();
                if(id != '-1'){
                    $.get('/admin/get-accounts/'+id, function(response){
                        let data = response.data;
                        if(data.length > 0){
                            $("select[name='account_id']").html("<option value='-1'>Seleccione</option>");
                            $.each(data, function(v,e){
                                $("select[name='account_id']").append("<option value='"+e.id+"'>"+e.email+"</option>");
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }else{
                    $("select[name='account_id']").html("<option>Seleccione</option>");
                }
            });

            $("select[name='account_id']").change(function(){
                let id = $(this).val();
                if(id != '-1'){
                    $.get('/admin/get-profiles/'+id, function(response){
                        let data = response.data;
                        if(data.length > 0){
                            $("select[name='profile_id']").html("<option value='-1'>Seleccione</option>");
                            $.each(data, function(v,e){
                                $("select[name='profile_id']").append("<option value='"+e.id+"'>"+e.name+" ("+e.pin+")</option>");
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }else{
                    $("select[name='profile_id']").html("<option value='-1'>Seleccione</option>");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@stop

Puedo notar que en la sección Script al final tiene una función Select que hace relación a controlador especificamente en la función getAccounts
mi SubscriptionController es el siguiente
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Subscription;
use App\Models\Service;
use App\Models\Movement;
use App\Models\Payment;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Account;
use Auth;
use Session;
use App\Helpers\Helper;
use App\Models\Profile;

class SubscriptionController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $title = "Suscripciones";

        $columns = [
            [
                'title'=>'Servicio',
                'key'=>'service_id',
                'type'=>'relation',
                'data'=>[
                    'relation'=>'service',
                    'key'=>'image_name',
                    'format'=>'html'
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Cuenta',
                'key'=>'account_id',
                'type'=>'relation',
                'data'=>[
                    'relation'=>'account',
                    'key'=>'email',
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Perfil',
                'key'=>'profile_id',
                'type'=>'relation',
                'data'=>[
                    'relation'=>'profile',
                    'key'=>'name',
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Cliente',
                'key'=>'customer_id',
                'type'=>'relation',
                'data'=>[
                    'relation'=>'customer',
                    'key'=>'name',
                ]
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Dias Restantes',
                'key'=>'last_days'
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Vence',
                'key'=>'date_to',
                'type'=>'date',
                 'data'=>[
                    'format'=>'d-m-Y'
                 ] 
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Enviar Datos',
                'key'=>'share_buttons',
                'type'=>'html'
            ],
            [
                'title'=>'Estado',
                'key'=>'real_status',
                'type'=>'html'
            ]
        ];

        $data = Subscription::all();

        return view('admin.subscriptions.browse', compact('title','columns', 'data'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $title = "Nueva Suscripción";
        $type = "new";
        $services = Service::all();
        $customers = Customer::all();
        return view('admin.subscriptions.add-edit', compact('title','type','services','customers'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'service_id'=>'required',
            'account_id'=>'required',
            'customer_id'=>'required',
            'profile_id'=>'required|numeric|min:1',
            'date_to'=>'required',
            'amount'=>'required'
        ]);

        $element = new Subscription();
        $element->service_id = $request->service_id;
        $element->account_id = $request->account_id;
        $element->customer_id = $request->customer_id;
        $element->profile_id = $request->profile_id;
        $element->date_to = $request->date_to;
        $element->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        if($element->save()){
            $payment = new Payment();
            $payment->customer_id = $element->customer_id;
            $payment->amount = $request->amount;
            if($payment->save()){
                $mvd = [
                    'type'=>'input',
                    'description'=>'Se Creo la suscripcion al servicio '.$element->service->name." de la cuenta con el correo ".$element->account->email.' para el cliente '.$element->customer->name,
                    'amount'=>$request->amount
                ];
                Movement::createMovement($mvd);
            }
            Session::flash('success', 'Registro Insertado con Exito!!');
        }else{
            Session::flash('error', 'Ocurrio un error al tratar de insertar el Registro!!');
        }

        return redirect()->route('subscriptions.index');
    }

    public function show(string $id)
    {

    }

    public function edit(string $id)
    {

    }

    public function update(Request $request, string $id)
    {

    }

    public function destroy(string $id)
    {
        $subscription = Subscription::find($id);
        if($subscription->delete()){
            Session::flash('success','Registro Eliminado con Exito!!');
        }else{
            Session::flash('error','Ocurrio un error al tratar de eliminar al Registro!!');
        }
        return redirect()->route('subscriptions.index');
    }

    public function getAccounts($service_id){
        $data = [];
        $attr = [
            'table'=>'accounts',
            'columns'=>[
                'id',
                'email'
            ],
            'compare'=>'service_id',
            'compare_value'=>$service_id
        ];
        
        $response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr);
        if($response){
            $data = $response;
            
            
        }

        return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
    }

    public function getProfiles($account_id){
        $data = [];
        $attr = [
            'table'=>'profiles',
            'columns'=>[
                'id',
                'name',
                'pin'
            ],
            'compare'=>'account_id',
            'compare_value'=>$account_id
        ];
        $response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr);
        if($response){
            foreach($response as $res){
                $profile = Profile::find($res->id);
                if($profile->subscriptions->count() == 0){
                    array_push($data, $res);
                }
            }
        }

        return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
    }

    public function extend_subscriptions(Request $request){
        $sub = Subscription::findorfail($request->id);
        $sub->date_to = $request->date_to;
        if($sub->update()){
            $payment = new Payment();
            $payment->customer_id = $sub->customer_id;
            $payment->amount = $request->amount;
            if($payment->save()){
                $mvd = [
                    'type'=>'input',
                    'description'=>'Se extendio la suscripcion al servicio '.$sub->service->name." de la cuenta con el correo ".$sub->account->email.' para el cliente '.$sub->customer->name,
                    'amount'=>$request->amount
                ];
                Movement::createMovement($mvd);
            }
            Session::flash('success','Suscripcion Extendida con Exito!!');
        }else{
            Session::flash('error','Error al extender la Membresia!!');
        }

        return redirect()->route('subscriptions.index');
    }
    public function my_account(){
        $accounts = Account::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
        return view('admin.subscriptions.add-edit', compact('accounts'));
    }
}

Veo que en la public function getAccounts
Se declara una variable $response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr)
y ese Helper tiene esto:
<?php

    namespace App\Helpers;

    use DB;
    use App\Models\User;
    use App\Models\Setting;

    class Helper{

        public static function getDataSelect($attr){
            if($attr){
                $data = DB::table($attr['table'])->select($attr['columns'])->where($attr['compare'],$attr['compare_value'])->get();
                return $data;
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static function addCredits(User $user, $credits){
            $currentCredits = $user->total_credits;
            $newCredits = floatval(($currentCredits + floatval($credits)));
            $user->total_credits = $newCredits;
            if($user->save()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static function removeCredits(User $user, $credits){
            $salida = -1;
            $currentCredits = $user->total_credits;

            if(floatval($currentCredits) < floatval($credits)){
                $salida = 2;
            }else{
                $newCredits = floatval(($currentCredits - floatval($credits)));
                $user->total_credits = $newCredits;
                if($user->save()){
                    $salida = 1;
                }else{
                    $salida = 0;
                }
            }
            
            return $salida;
        }

        public static function currentSymbol(){
            $data = Setting::first();
            $symbol = "$";
            if(!empty($data->currency)){
                $response = json_decode($data->currency, true);
                $symbol = $response['symbol'];
            }

            return $symbol;
        }

    }

Improvisando un poco yo hice este cambio en la funcion getAccounts
public function getAccounts($service_id){
        $data = [];
        $attr = [
            'table'=>'accounts',
            'columns'=>[
                'id',
                'email'
            ],
            'compare'=>'service_id',
            'compare_value'=>$service_id
        ];
        
        $response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr);
        if($response){
            $data = $response;
 // he añadido esta linea a continuación////////////////////////////////
 //         $data = Account::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////            
        }

        return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
    }

Ha funcionado de momento en la sesion de adminsitrador y en la revendedor, pero a veces no funciona (no muestra las cuentas) yo creo que tiene algun tipo de conflicto, habrá que declarar esa variable diferente o y pasarla pero a nivel de codigo no se como hacerlo o como colocar eso o en que partes debo hacer el arreglo, si alguien puede ayudarme le agradecería....
no se si en el script de la vista se pueda cambiar algo para que en vez de ver toda las cuentas pueda ver solo las que me pertenecen o le pertenecen a ese user_id
1:

Vender cuentas de netflix que no son tuyas es ilegal, y acorde a las reglas de netflix tampoco puedes vender la tuya... cuidado :)

@Benito-B yo no vendo cuentas, vendo sistemas y paginas web, si no lo tengo lo compro y lo vendo, gracias por tu gran aporte :)

Creo que el problema viene de los datos en la DB. Debes revisar ahí

Gracias. he modificado la función en el Helper, y ahora he colocado esto
`public static function getDataSelect($attr,$user_id=null){
if($attr){
if($user_id){
$data = DB::table($attr['table'])->select($attr['columns'])->where($attr['compare'],$attr['compare_value'])->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
}else{
$data = DB::table($attr['table'])->select($attr['columns'])->where($attr['compare'],$attr['compare_value'])->get();
}
return $data;

}else{
return null;
}
}` ya funciona

yo creo que tienes dos problemas
uno es en getAccounts() y otro getProfiles()
tu pusiste algo así en getAccounts()
  // he añadido esta linea a continuación////////////////////////////////
  //         $data = Account::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)- 
 >get();

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

deberías tener en cuenta también el service_id ,
entonces , debería quedar asi
  $data = Account::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('service_id', $service_id)->get();

esto según como esta el código que pasaste. Aparentemente el service_id también es importante.
Pero ahí tienes otro problema. como identificar al administrador para que le salgan todos los servicios y cuentas
si tienes algún campo en la tabla para identificar al usuario administrador como por ejemplo
 Auth::user()->role_id   //por ejemplo  

o si sabes cual es el id del super admin
 Auth::user()->id == 1    //por ejemplo

entonces el código quedaría así:
 // si es el usuario administrador
 if(Auth::user()->id == 1) {
    $data = Account::where('service_id', $service_id)->get();
 } else {
     // si es un usuario comun
     $data = Account::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('service_id', $service_id)->get();
 }

en el formulario de altas aparentemente se utiliza getProfiles()
entonces ahí también podrías poner el código modificado
   public function getProfiles($account_id){
      $data = [];
      $attr = [
        'table'=>'profiles',
        'columns'=>[
            'id',
            'name',
            'pin'
        ],
        'compare'=>'account_id',
        'compare_value'=>$account_id
     ];

    
    //$response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr);

    //aquí seria tu código modificado
    // si es el usuario administrador
      if(Auth::user()->id == 1) {
         $response = Profile::all();
      } else {
        // si es un usuario comun
        $response = Profile::whereIn('account_id',Profile::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get()->pluck('id');
     }

    if($response){
        foreach($response as $res){
            $profile = Profile::find($res->id);
            if($profile->subscriptions->count() == 0){
                array_push($data, $res);
            }
        }
    }

    return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
}

Saludos

Gracias amigo Hugo, he intentado con lo que me has pasado pero no ha funcionado, pero he tenido una duda en esto que me has enviado: en el getAccounts() en la variable $data = $response va a quedar completamente reemplazada por $data = Account::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('service_id', $service_id)->get(); ? o que sucede con $response? debo hacer lo mismo que hiciste en el getProfiles() en la sección de //$response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr);? Muchas gracias

Hola. disculpa la demora.

Si, la variable $response queda reemplazada por $data . Porque $response viene desde la función   getDataSelect().  Lo que estamos haciendo es reemplazar lo que hace la función getDataSelect() directamente con la variable $data. Si te fijas en tu codigo original hay una linea que hace    $data = $response;.

en la funcion getProfiles() se utiliza solo la variable $response.

Muchas gracias amigo hugo, pude solucionarlo haciendo lo que comentaste
